# Can you say «they make me scared» in English?

Tags: spoken-english, translation

Can you say

> They make me scared

My English teacher said that we cannot say it so I looked for it on the Internet.

That in a test, the set point was "Traduisez les phrases en anglais (Translate the sentences in English)" and the sentence was "Je déteste les films d'horreur, ils me font peur." and I translated:

> "I hate horror movie, they make me scared."

Comment: [Yes](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3A+books.google.com+%22make+me+scared%22&btnG=&gws_rd=ssl). I'm not sure why your teacher said you could not use it. What's the context?

Comment: Are you sure the teacher was referring to "They make me scared"? I'd say the error is in the first part of your translation, not the second (the word _movie_ should be pluralized).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with "They make me scared", though "They scare me" is more direct.

You should use the plural, and if you are writing for a test, you should use a semicolon (to avoid a comma splice): "I hate horror movies; they scare me."